# add conditions using pywraplp in ortools

Tags: or-tools

i am using pywraplp but had difficulty to set variable constraint conditionally to another variable.

```
c = solver.IntVar(0,6,f'c_{i}')
x = solver.BoolVar(f'x_{i}')
```

I want to add constraint or sth like :

```
solver.Add(c[i]=0 if x[i] is false)
```

anyone can help? thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`solver.Add(x <= M * c)` with M >= max(x)

Note that:

- It only works if M is finite
- It needs a MIP solver (a LP solver will not work)
- If M is large, numerical tolerance makes the constraint weak

If the problem does not have continuous variables, I suggest using CP-SAT

```
model.Add(x == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(c.Not())
```

Comment: thank you Laurent, I was using cp-sat and OnlyEnforceIf. but I am wondering if there is a way to add conditions in pywraplp.

I actually has x<=M*c where M is finite value and not greater than 12. I will try it with MIP solver, such as SCIP?

Comment: The equation I wrote is the way to go. I would expect that if you can run with enough threads (8?), CP-SAT will outperform SCIP.

Comment: there is reason that I need to export the model as MPS format, therefore I can only use pywraplp. By using pywraplp I can solve the problem within 16 mins (though it is still long for my applicaion), however, the problem took longer time to solve while loaded this MPS file and the **CP-SAT** solver was applied. settings as follows: `log_search_progress: true num_workers: 16` on a server which has 32 cores.

Comment: more logs for the references:
`#Variables: 6'355'788 (#bools: 5'727'634 in floating point objective)
  - 6'249'120 Booleans in [0,1]
  - 106668 constants in {0} 
#kLinearN: 132'487 (#terms: 24'842'496)`

Comment: Can you send me the mps ? and/or the cp_model proto ?